# How to copy (or delete etc.) multiple files (or directories) using the Windows dialog?

Tags: c#, windows

My main question is: How to do file operations with the user being able to cancel them in the middle.

I know I can use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace like: `FileSystem.DeleteFile(...)` but that only gives me an option for one file. I would like to delete many files together. (And the same goes for copying...)

Note: I need the user to be able to cancel the operation if needed even in the middle of copying a large file, not just between files. I know I can do that with unmanaged code (-`CopyFileEx`) but I'm looking for a managed way to do that, whether or not it uses the native Windows dialog.

EDIT: I've been suggested 'wrappers' for unmanaged code and 'manual' copying and deleting (in the answers below). Is there an in-built way (like the VisualBasic namespace stuff - but for multiple files) that I'm missing?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Huh?? It's in the question. Or did you mean `File.Delete` which obviously won't help here?

Comment: I was wondering if you had a code sample of what you are actually doing that is what I meant..

Comment: Check the properties and see use the Delete Option with the Cancel option as well for your usecase

Comment: are you looking for something like in the Example I posted below..? the link should help to get you started on what you are looking for

Comment: The simple native API for this is SHFileOperation.  There does not appear to be a .NET equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of copying, you will need to do this manually by copying the file in chunks and each time you process a chunk you'll check if the user set a cancel flag.

```
void CopyStream(Stream in, Stream out) 
{ 
    var buf = new byte[512]; 

    int bytesRead; 
    while((bytesRead = in.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0) 
    { 
        out.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead); 
        if(cancelled)
        { 
           // Do you cancel routine
           return; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

For delete, your best bet is you process the file delete one at a time and do the same type of process I describe above.

Advantage of this is that it will work regardless of operating system.  It will work regardless of the types of files.  It will work regardless of whatever threading you are implementing.

Comment: It seems there is no simple managed way to do it. (As said in Luke's comment above.)

Answer (score 2):

I know as far a a Copy Method you could do something like this and using the Microsoft.VisualBasic NameSpace will not hurt your code check out the Article in this link

The IFileOperation shell interface, available since Vista.  A managed class wrapper for this COM interface is available in this [magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163304.aspx).

Fall back on your existing code if it also needs to run on earlier versions of Windows.

[image: Copy File with Progress and Cancel Option]